# Why is the \listoffigures command not working?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing my dissertation using LaTeX and I'm having some problems when using `\listoffigures`. The `\listoftables` command works perfectly, but the `\listoffigures` command does not recognize the many figures in the text.

What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also you can take at look at the log file, there is where appears the errors and sometimes suggestios for fix them.

Comment: Do you mean that `\listoffigures` skips some figures?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the user (who didn't post an MWE) solved the problem by himself/herself.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I realized that the caption was in the \subfigure environment.